# How can I convert matrix to different matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix, split

Here I have some codes generating a matrix like this:

```
N = 200
T = 10
mu_0 <- matrix(diag(1, T))
dim(mu_0) <- c(T,T)
mu_t_0 <- matrix(rep(t(mu_0), N), ncol = T, byrow = TRUE)
```

And generally the result looks like this

```
   V1   V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
11  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
16  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
17  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
20  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
...
```

Now for later calculation I want to split this large matrix into different small matrices like this:

Matrix One:

```
1  
0 
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

Matrix Two:

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
...
```

I tried the split function but I cannot get what I want. Are there any solutions?

Comment: This depends on what you want to do. Often you can leave the "small matrices" within the large one and manipulate them there. Most often this is more efficient and results in nicer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one puts all the columns into a list.

```
res <- lapply(1:ncol(mu_t_0), function(i) mu_t_0[, i, drop=F])

head(res[[1]])
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    0

head(res[[2]])
#      [,1]
# [1,]    0
# [2,]    1
# [3,]    0
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    0
```

To extract the single one column matrices use `list2env`; the objects in the list need `names` beforehand.

```
names(res) <- paste0("m.", 1:length(res))
list2env(res, env=.GlobalEnv)
ls()
# [1] "m.1"    "m.10"   "m.2"    "m.3"    "m.4"    "m.5"    "m.6"    "m.7"    "m.8"    "m.9"    "mu_0"   "mu_t_0"
# [13] "N"      "res"    "T"
```

Comment: Thank you! It really helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `asplit` to *split an array or matrix by its margin*.

```
x <- asplit(mu_t_0, 2)
str(x)
#List of 10
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
# $ : num [1:2000(1d)] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
# - attr(*, "dim")= int 10
```

Comment: Do I need to install packages when using asplit? Because after I run this code I got an error: Error in asplit(mu_t_0, 2) : could not find function "asplit".

Comment: `asplit` is in `base`. So no need install packages. May be try `base::aslpit`.

Comment: Yes it's there since `3.6.0`.

Comment: It worked after I updated a newer version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want individual vectors named in the global environment (i.e. object V1, V2, and etc.):

```
invisible(mapply(assign, names(as.data.frame(mu_t_0)),  as.data.frame(mu_t_0), MoreArgs=list(envir = globalenv())))
```

Though I'm really interested in why the OP doesn't want to just work with a single matrix...

Comment: Just noticed second part of jay.sf's answer does the same - will leave this answer as it gives a single line alternative.